# Shopify basic price indication

Tags: shopify, liquid

I try to make a basic price indication for my german Shopify store. In this line, I've tried to give out the basic price, which is: product.price / first variant value * 10 but I don't know how to get the value from that. Maybe someone can help me with this.

I hope my description is complete.

(there are 3 sets of variants but only the 1. is important so it has to be something like product options selector = 0 or something)

THX!

```
 <p class="hint">Grundpreis: {{ product.price | divided_by: product.option.selected_value | times: 10 | money }}/Meter</p> 
 </p>



   <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-{{ section.id }}{% unless current_variant.available %} product-price--sold-out{% endunless %}">
        {% if current_variant.compare_at_price > current_variant.price %}
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
            <s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}">{{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s>
            <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }} product-price__sale product-price__sale--single">
              <span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}"    
                itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
                {{ current_variant.price | money }}
              </span>
              <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }}">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
            </span>
        {% else %}
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
          <s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}" class="hide">{{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s>
          <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }}">
            <span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}"
              itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
              {{ current_variant.price | money }}
            </span>
            <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }} hide">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
          </span>
        {% endif %}  
        <p class="hint">Grundpreis: {{ product.price | divided_by: product.option.selected_value | money }}/Meter</p> 
      </p>

      <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-{{ section.id }}{% unless section.settings.show_variant_labels %} product-form--hide-variant-labels{% endunless %}" data-section="{{ section.id }}">
        {% unless product.options.size == 1 and product.variants[0].title == 'Default Title' %}
          {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
            <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
              <label {% if option.name == 'default' %}class="label--hidden" {% endif %}for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                {{ option.name }}
              </label>
              <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
                {% for value in option.values %}
                  <option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endunless %}
```

Comment: What is this variable? `product.option.selected_value` product object doesn't have this variable.  You told that you trying to achieve `product.price / first variant value * 10 `. But what do you mean by `first variant value`?

Comment: I found out now that <p class="hint">Grundpreis: {{ product.price | times:current_variant.option1 | divided_by:1000 | money}}/Meter</p> would be the right way to do it, but when i do so, it only cals the prince once and not for everx product :/

Comment: I am still not sure, what are you trying to achieve. You said for `every product`? Do you mean for every product variant?